# Handling null values in column using oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, null

I have a query for which it returns `null` values for some column. So I want to replace it that with `-`. So below is my query

```
IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'APPLICATION' THEN   
 STREX:='SELECT AM.APPLICATIONNAME, AM.PROJECTNO, AM.VSS_FOLDER_LOC 
           FROM APPLICATION_MASTER AM 
                INNER JOIN APPLICATION_DETAILS AD
                   ON AM.APP_MST_ID = AD.APP_MST_ID 
          WHERE AM.'|| UPPER(P_PARAM_TYPE) ||' '|| P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NVL](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php) is the way to go.
Try this :

```
    IF P_SEARCH_TYPE = 'APPLICATION' THEN   
     STREX:='SELECT NVL(AM.APPLICATIONNAME,''-''), AM.PROJECTNO, AM.VSS_FOLDER_LOC 
               FROM APPLICATION_MASTER AM 
                    INNER JOIN APPLICATION_DETAILS AD
                       ON AM.APP_MST_ID = AD.APP_MST_ID 
              WHERE AM.'|| UPPER(P_PARAM_TYPE) ||' '|| P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM';
```

you must [escape](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/quotes.php) the quote character

Answer (score 0):

NVL function is used for such a purpose.

Comment: is this fine `'SELECT NVL(AM.APPLICATIONNAME,'-')` ?